# Android Package_replaced BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I've already tried several things and now I've put all actions into one receiver:

```
  <receiver android:name=".ReceiverClass">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is my Receiver class

```
public class ReceiverClass extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("test");
    }



    if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "6", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    }
}
```

None of the Toasts get displayed, when I manuall install a new signed APK. Is there something I am missing as the only really replied posts are from 2015 or even earlier. Time flies.

Comment: A registration is needed to use that? I'm using the same code as yours but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

`ACTION_PACAKGE_INSTALL` has never been used, according to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#action_package_install).

`ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` is only broadcast to you [if your own app is being upgraded](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#action_my_package_replaced). You will not receive it for changes in other apps.

The other three you cannot register for in the manifest on Android 8.0+, as implicit broadcasts are banned and those actions are not on [the whitelist](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Even just with ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED it doesn't work. Is there like a special way to test it as I've read here and there?

Comment: @TesterOlaf: "Even just with ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED it doesn't work" -- that should work AFAIK, if you upgrade your own app. That is "broadcast" just to your app, so it is already exempt from the implicit broadcast restriction. Personally, I have not had a need to use it much, so I cannot comment on testing it.

Comment: whats the solution for this ?

Comment: @FerozSiddiqui: I do not know what overall problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @CommonsWare please help me and have a look at this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386167/android-how-to-get-a-callback-in-app-when-app-gets-autoupdate-in-google-playst

Comment: @FerozSiddiqui: You should be able to register for `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` in the manifest.

Comment: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action. ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED.   I am getting this

Comment: @FerozSiddiqui: I doubt that, since that is not the correct `Intent` action string.